# What's the point of CD drive offsets?

Tags: ripping, dvd-burning

Why are there different offsets for CD Drives, what's does the read and write offsets mean? How can I know the offset for my CD/DVD writer?

Answer (score 2):

From AccurateRip's site.

> Each CD drive reads audio discs slightly out (a number of samples), if
>   your CD drive supports 'Accurate Stream' it will be a constant value,
>   this value tends to be the same for each particular make and model of
>   CD Drive. A small number of drives have [Purged] as the offset, these
>   drives were found not to have a constant drive offset (perhaps
>   different manufacturing batches, or firmwares), as such they have been
>   removed from AccurateRip's drive database (should you have one of
>   these drives, 3 matching key disks will be required to configure
>   AccurateRip).

[The page](http://www.accuraterip.com/driveoffsets.htm) contains a list of known Drive's in AccurateRip's database and their respective offsets.